# How do I use SwiftUI Bindings to create a var?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI with two bindings as an example. I want to create a range from these two bindings.

```
@Binding var lowerBound:Double
@Binding var upperBound:Double
```

Now I want to initialize my slider with a range. So I thought this would work:

```
var range = lowerBound...upperBound
```

but where does this go? If I put it below

```
var body: some View {
        var range = lowerBound...upperBound
```

I get this error:

```
Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
```

How do I make vars from bindings?

Comment: you could create a viewmodel which creates the var range when setting lowerBound and upperBound

Comment: Your approach feels... wrong. First, the issue is that you declare variables *outside* of `some View`, not inside. Second, why not just use your two variables *as is*? A SwiftUI `Slider` needs a parameter called `in`, which *is* this range you are trying to do. My SwiftUI sliders use three (and soon four) `ObservableObject` variables set up as an array of a `struct` - min, max, default, and soon - step. Not to sound harsh, but it sounds like you haven't "grokked" some SwiftUI basics. (BTW, I didn't downvote you.)

Answer (score 0):

I was to new to SwiftUI. My problem was one of having to explicitly declare a return view. One cannot commingle logic with views. If so you must declare what the view you are returning. That was causing my compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a slider with SwiftUI you don't need a range. see the below example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 200
    @State private var lowerBound: Double = 10
    @State private var upperBound: Double = 1000

    var body: some View {
        CustomButton(sliderValue: $sliderValue, lowerBound: lowerBound, upperBound: upperBound)
    }
}

struct CustomButton: View {
    @Binding var sliderValue: Double
    var lowerBound: Double
    var upperBound: Double

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $sliderValue, from: lowerBound, through: upperBound, by: 10)
        .padding()        
    }
 }
```

Based on SwiftUI Slider document to initialize a slider you need to follow this signature:

public init(value: Binding, from minValue: V = 0.0, through maxValue: V = 1.0, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }) where V : BinaryFloatingPoint, V.Stride : BinaryFloatingPoint

- value: The selected value within `minValue...maxValue
- minValue: The beginning of the range of the valid values. Defaults
  to `0.0`
- maxValue: The end of the range of valid values. Defaults to `1.0`.

And you can see the first argument is a binding and minValue and maxValue are not binding.

Answer (score -1):

I since learned a lot. It was necessary to use both @State and @Environment objects  in the init and in the call back .

Here is my SQL Generator example that this is all based upon. It uses bindings with a picker and a slider!

https://github.com/jimijon/SwiftUI-SQL-ExpMaker

Comment: you must use property wrappers as designed not try to use them in init